# Dealing with Multiple Capybara React-select dropdowns?

Tags: selenium, automation, capybara

So I have a page with multiple dropdowns (with the same choices) when automating a webpage using Capybara and Chromedriver.

They are all react-select's (Which I have a helper file for). Sadly they ALL have the same label text (but not label ID....however I don't think `page.select` works for label ID).

I thought about doing a page.all on the react-selects? and then just going through the array? Is that possible?

the react-select looks pretty standard, I realize the span has an id but selecting by that doesn't work for react-selects from what i've been able to tell.:

```
<div class="Select-control">
   <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-6--value">
      <div class="Select-placeholder">Select...</div>
      <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
         <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-6--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;">
         <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre;"></div>
      </div>
   </span>
   <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
</div>
```

Could I maybe just pull it in via page.all? The react helper I have does this:

```
module CapybaraReactHelper
  def capybara_react_select(selector, label)
    within selector do
      find('.Select-control').click
      expect(page).to have_css('.Select-menu-outer') # options should now be available
      expect(page).to have_css('.Select-option', text: label)
      find('.Select-option', text: label).click
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.select` doesn't work for this because it only works for HTML `<select>` elements.  This is a JS driven widget, not an HTML `<select>` element.

If you are just automating a page (not testing an app) it'll probably be easier just to use JS (via `execute_script`) to set the value of the hidden `<input>`s.

If you are testing an app, then you can use `page.all` to gather all the react-selects and step through, as long as selecting from any react-select doesn't replace any of the others on the page (which would leave you with obsolete elements).

If that doesn't provide enough info to solve your problem, and your real issue is trying to pick a specific react-select to select from, then please add enough HTML to your question so we can see what actual differences exist between the widgets you're trying to choose from (2 different react-select elements for instance)

Comment: `page.all` ended up being my solution. I was able to do something similar to `stuffgoeshere = page.all("div.Select--single")` and then do a `within(stuffgoeshere)` (in a for loop) etc....

problem is I have a ton of dropdowns on the page, and it doesn't want to scroll down. I've updated chromedriver as apparently that was an issue before....but what causes it to actually auto-scroll. I hate having to use `window.scrollby`

Comment: @msmith1114 Are you just selecting the same thing from every "select" on the page?  As for scorlling, when you click on an element, chromedriver should scroll it into view before clicking it - What error exactly are you getting and what exactly is the line of code is producing that error.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Scrolling is working now with 2.32 chromedriver update. I have a floating footer than is intercepting clicks (blocking them). Unfortunately theirs not really a good way to just turn this "footer" off.

Is there some trick to delete or hide the element while tests are running within capybara/selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting by the `id` on `.Select-multi-value-wrapper` isn't working because that `span` isn't the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) component's top-level tag. Working with react-select and Capybara generally is difficult because the Capybara form helpers won't work with react-select's custom markup and behavior.

As you've mentioned, you can get around this by using a version of your existing helper with a scoping `within` block and `page.all()`. For example:

```
# helper
def react_select_capybara(selector, option)
  within selector do
    find('.Select-arrow-zone').click
    expect(page).to have_css('.Select-menu-outer')
    find('.Select-option', text: option).click
    expect(page).to have_css('.Select-value-label', text: option)
  end
end

# usage
given(:select_values) { ['Grace Hopper', 'Ada Lovelace'] }

...

react_selects = page.all('.Select')

select_values.each do |select_value, i|
  react_select_capybara(react_selects[i], select_value)
end
```

While this will work, it is brittle - it relies on the implicit ordering of your react-selects on the page. A more robust setup would pass each react-select component a custom classname to uniquely identify it in your test. From the [react-select docs on custom classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#custom-classnames):

> You can provide a custom className prop to the  component, which will be added to the base .Select className for the outer container.

Implementing this might look like:

```
# JSX
<ReactSelect className="js-select-user-form-1" ... />    
<ReactSelect className="js-select-user-form-2" ... />     

# Spec
react_select_capybara(".js-select-user-form-1", 'Grace Hopper')
react_select_capybara(".js-select-user-form-2", 'Ada Lovelace')
```